# how can I detect charset of a web page

Tags: java, encoding, character-encoding, html

I just want to get the web page source in java language and I just want to get that content with correct encoding type. I am able to get the content of a web page till now. But for some web pages the content comes with absurd characters. So I need to detect charset of that web page.

According to my little research I found that there is a jChardet library to do this. But I couldn't import it to my project. Can someone please help me?

By the way the code below is the code to read the web page content

```
  StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(); 
  InputStream is = fURL.openStream();
  BufferedReader buffer = null;
  buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, encodingType));

  int byteRead;
  while ((byteRead = buffer.read()) != -1) {
    builder.append((char) byteRead);
  }
  buffer.close();  

  return builder;
```

Answer (score 4):

Read the `Content-Type` header of the HTTP response, it's the best way to get the charset. Only apply guessing when you have no alternatives - you do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use too the http://jchardet.sourceforge.net/

```
private static String detectCharset(byte[] body) {
        nsDetector det = new nsDetector(nsPSMDetector.ALL);



        det.Init(new nsICharsetDetectionObserver() {

            public void Notify(String charset) {
                HtmlCharsetDetector.found = true;
            }
        });

        boolean done = false;
        boolean isAscii = true;

        if (isAscii) {
            isAscii = det.isAscii(body, body.length);
        }

        // DoIt if non-ascii and not done yet.
        if (!isAscii && !done) {
            done = det.DoIt(body, body.length, false);
        }

        return det.getProbableCharsets()[0];

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Minimally, you would need to read and parse the HTTP headers to see whether they declare the encoding in HTTP headers and, in the absence of such a declaration (rather common), parse the document itself to find a `meta` tag that declares the encoding. For XHTML documents, you would need to check the XML declaration and default to utf-8. This would still leave a considerable amount of pages with undeclared encoding, so some heuristics would be needed. You might check the [section on encodings](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/parsing.html#character-encodings-0) in the HTML5 draft, which contains some heuristic overrides too (e.g., treating iso-8859-1 as windows-1252).