# Input text in other language changes to random characters

Tags: java, html, css, jsp

I have 2 JSP pages, one for pending accounts and other for active accounts. On both the pages I have an input box for Company Name. When I enter Japanese characters in the Company Name on pending accounts page, the text changes to some random characters and hence search does not work based on Company Name. But when I perform the search based on Company Name with Japanese characters on active accounts page, it works flawlessly. The only difference in the two pages is that pending accounts page is using   tags for separating all the input fields and aligning them, but active accounts page is using  for the same with specific CSS classes. Could this be a reason for the difference in this behavior or am I missing something?

Comment: It sounds like a problem with the charset being used on the page. Have a look at this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8636215/how-can-i-detect-charset-of-a-web-page it may be it's set to using ASCII but you most likely want UTF-8.

Comment: I already have this line on all my JSP pages `<%@page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>`

Comment: Adding `response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");` to the servlet method solved the problem. Thanks for giving me a direction.